# Unable to send email to the same domain from which it's sent via SendGrid

Tags: email, tcp, dns, sendgrid

My setup is as follows:

- VPS running on DigitalOcean
- DNS running on DigitalOcean (managing the domain XYZ.com which directs to the VPS)
- day-to-day business email running in a 3rd party provider service (with addresses like name@XYZ.com)
- transactional email API (SendGrid) using the same domain as the VPS and business email (XYZ.com)

My problem is, whenever I try to send some transactional email via SendGrid to one of my business addresses I get the messages blocked with the following notification from SendGrid:

> error dialing remote address: dial tcp <SOME_IP_HERE>:0-><ANOTHER_IP_HERE>:25:
> i/o timeout

I reckon the issue might me sending and receiving the email from the same domain, however, I have no idea how to tackle this. What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out it was an issue with anty-spoof filter on my business email. I turned it off and it all works now.

Comment: Where did you off Anti Spoofing?

Comment: My email is hosted on Private Email, which is managed by Namecheap. I just went to the email management tab and turned off the "Anti-Spoof Filter" option.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error "`error dialing remote address: dial tcp`" when trying to send emails **from no-reply@custom.com to support@custom.com**. I contacted SendGrid Support and they responded that the error is with MX records on the recipient domain. Furthermore, they added:

> Checking further, this error indicates that the email recipient server
> timed out while attempting to accept the emails from SendGrid. If you
> are not able to whitelist the domain, you might need to reach out to
> the admin/postmaster of your domain to get more insights about it and
> lift the block so that you can start receiving the emails.

I contacted my domain provider and they solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Check sendgrid

> `
> Suppressions -> (Bounces, Blocks)

`

option. some times sendgrid block the mail